# declaring c# function

Tags: c#

I created a class called MyClass somewhat like this:

```
public class MyClass
{ public int MyInt {get;set;}
  public int MyInt2 {get;set;}
}
```

Now I'd like to create a function that accepts an int as a parameter and that returns a list of MyClass objects.

I'm stuck on syntax. Is is `public static List<MyClass> MyFunction (int MyParam)`? I'm not getting intellisense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely want:

```
public static List<MyClass> MyFunction(int myParam)
{
    // ....
```

[`List<MyClass>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) is a generic list, which is the best option (since it's type safe) for a list of MyClass.  It will require adding `using System.Collections.Generic;` to the top of your file (or fully qualifying it).

Comment: If you're not getting intellisense on the list part, then ensure you have a "using System.Collections.Generic;" at the top of the file/namespace.

Comment: A return type of `IList<MyClass>` may allow for more flexibility.  Even if the developer doesn't need it, a little nudge towards an understanding of interfaces couldn't hurt.

Comment: @David: True - `IEnumerable<MyClass>` could be even better.  (Though, I must admit, `List<T>` is often used as a "special" case in the framework and returned directly - methods like ToList() could have returned `IList<T>` but don't...)

Comment: I generally go with `IEnumerable<>` myself as well (or rather, with the highest common abstraction), but it will depend on what the developer needs to do here.  We don't have enough understanding of the code, and he may need actual list functionality (add, remove, etc.) in common places.  Sure, there's always `.ToList()`, but if the method should always return a list then there's no reason to abstract further.

Answer (score 0):

`public static List<MyClass> MyFunction(int myParam) { }` seems like ok syntax to accept an int parameter, and return a list of MyClass instances.

If you're not getting intellisense support (assuming you're using VS.NET), you may have some syntax errors in your source code.

Speaking of intellisense, if you hit `Ctrl + .` over any type in your source file in VS.NET, and VS.NET will automatically search that type and add an using statement to your source file for you.